# Store Multiple Identical Results from Logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

So, say I have an event coming into Logstash as a multiline object (there are many events that all basically match the pattern below):

```
Starting script at 2015-11-12 15:06 EST
Found result a at 127.0.0.1
Found result b at 127.0.0.1
Found result c at 0.0.0.0
Script ended at 2015-11-12 15:07 EST
```

How would I go about matching this in such a way as to store each of the "Found ..." lines separately?

My current config file is something like:

```
filter {
  grok {
    break_on_match => false
    match => { 
      "message" => [
        "Starting script at ${TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:run_time}",
        "Found result %{GREEDYDATA:result} at ${IP:result_ip}" 
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As it stands, this only captures one of the "Found result..." lines. (That is, it matches them all, but only stores one of them - there's only one `result` variable output.) I'd like to individually capture them, and store them as an... well, anything, so long as they're all there.

Is there a way to capture multiple of the same pattern and store all of the resultant capture data distinctly, while keeping the whole multiline event together so that I can tie it to header data such as the script start time?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the split filter to achieve what you want. It allows you to split one event into several parts. The indivdual parts are all copies of the original event as far as I remember. You have to play with the terminator parameter which controls when the message is split into parts.

Check out the docs at: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-split.html#plugins-filters-split-target